# Why does Google Cloud DNS return NOERROR instead of NXDOMAIN despite no A record?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, google-cloud-dns

I created a private DNS zone on GCP for `***redacted***.com`, and added only a CNAME record for a subdomain that doesn't resolve any IP address, `subdomain.***redacted***.com`. That's all. There is no A record or something else. Under these circumstances, I expected to see `NXDOMAIN` when I queried the A record, however the DNS server returned `NOERROR`. Why?

[image]

On the other hand, when I queried some FQDNs with the same conditions above, I observed that `NXDOMAIN` was returned as the response, instead of `NOERROR`.

[image]

I want to reproduce the same behaviour (returning `NXDOMAIN`) in Google Cloud DNS. How can I achieve this?